# ReactJS and Redux - Submit Form From Multiple Events (Not Buttons)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

**TO SUMMARIZE**: how can I submit a React JS Redux Form *without* a submit button (IE from componentDidUpdate, or a custom function)?

---

I have an interface (built in React JS) where a user needs to 'score' multiple items, back to back. IE, they'll have 'item 1', and assign it 1, 2, or 3 stars, then click 'next', which will take them to 'item 2', which they then give 1, 2, or 3 stars... and so on, until they've reached the end. There is *also* a navigation menu that lets them 'jump' to any item they want, if they so desire.

Due to the, ah, nature of the users we're dealing with, the interface was designed with the idea in mind that 'scoring' an individual item would immediately save that item's score (a `POST` call to a remote API). That way, if they exit, and come back, their progress is still there. I'm handling API functionality via Redux Sagas, and this particular component is a Redux form.

The Redux form is a component, and then the individual items within the form are their own components. IE:

```
ItemsComponent // <-- this is the connected Redux form
    ItemComponent // <-- this contains the individual item, the stars for scoring, etc.
```

The issue I'm encountering is that it is seemingly incredibly difficult to submit a Redux form 'on demand'. I *need* to submit this form programmatically, not via a submit button, but Redux and/or React seem to wall me off every way I try to do that.

The closest I've come is passing a clickHandler to the ItemComponent, which performs some other functionality first, then calls `handleSubmit(this.submit`) - however, while it's not returning me an *error*, it seems to simply not be triggering.

```
clickHandler = (item) => {
    console.log(item) // <-- this triggers
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props
    handleSubmit(this.submit) // <-- this does not return me any error
}

submit = (values) => {
    console.log('submit') // <-- this never triggers
}
```

In short, how can I trigger a Redux form submit *without* using a submit button? Ideally, from within a clickHandler of some kind?

---

My Items Component:

```
class ItemsComponent extends Component {
    ...
}

const formed = reduxForm({
    form: 'itemsform',
})(ItemsComponent)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: state.getItemsReducer, // <-- Redux Saga Reducer
    }
}

const connected = connect(
    mapStateToProps, {
        getItemsRequest, // <-- Redux Saga Action
    }
)(formed)
```

My store is attached via the router:

```
const store = createStore(  
    IndexReducer, // <-- combined Redux reducers
    composeSetup(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)

...

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            ...
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you connecting your components to the Redux store?

Comment: Updated the question to include my connected component code (heavily truncated of course), and the store (via Provider wrapping a Router).

Answer (score 0):

Following [the official documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/remotesubmit/) about submitting the form by dispatching an action we have the following:

RemoteSubmitButton.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { submit } from 'redux-form'

const style = {
  padding: '10px 20px',
  width: 140,
  display: 'block',
  margin: '20px auto',
  fontSize: '16px'
}

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({ dispatch }) =>
  <button
    type="button"
    style={style}
    onClick={() => dispatch(submit('remoteSubmit'))}>Submit</button>
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ name of the form

export default connect()(RemoteSubmitButton)
```

In your case you extract `dispatch(submit('remoteSubmit'))` into your actions and call that action within a connected component's `componentDidUpdate`